# Maven project with FreeMarker 2.3.23 dependeny doesn't compile

Tags: java, maven, freemarker

In my Maven project (Java 1.6.45) I want to use FreeMarker. When I add the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.23</version>
</dependency>
```

The project does not compile. For example, it cannot find class `freemarker.template.Configuration`. When I change version to 2.3.22, everything is fine. Do you have any idea what is the reason for this? Anyone tried to use FreeMarker 2.3.23 with Maven?

Comment: [`freemarker.template.Configuration`](http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/Configuration.html#VERSION_2_3_23) is definitely present in version 2.3.23 so the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by cleaning my local Maven repository. After that project compiled successfully with 2.3.23 version.